# Porque o erro " SCRIPT1004: ';' esperado" é gerado ao executar a aplicação no Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, syntax-error

Criei recentemente uma aplicação JavaScript que funciona perfeitamente no navegador *Chrome* e ontem eu resolvi testá-la no *Internet Explorer*.

Para a minha surpresa, a página não estava do jeito que deveria estar e além disso, ao abrir o console do navegador eu me deparei com essa pilha de erros:

```
SCRIPT1004: ';' esperado
Arquivo: main.js Linha: 74 Coluna: 20
SCRIPT1006: ')' esperado
Arquivo: progressBar.js Linha: 12 Coluna: 45
SCRIPT1006: ')' esperado
Arquivo: stopwatch.js Linha: 30 Coluna: 47
SCRIPT5009: 'createTriangle' não está definido
Arquivo: index.html Linha: 34 Coluna: 13
```

Na aba **depurador** ele mostra o seguinte erro:

> 'createTriangle' não está definido

Abaixo está um pedaço do meu código (o meu código inteiro está [aqui](https://github.com/JeanExtreme002/Stopwatch) no GitHub) que é a parte onde o navegador aponta o erro:

```js
function createTriangle(element){

    var triangle = document.createElement("div");
    triangle.setAttribute("class","triangle-right");
    element.appendChild(triangle);

    triangle.style.left = element.offsetWidth / 2 - triangle.offsetWidth / 2 + "px";
    triangle.style.top = element.offsetHeight / 2 - triangle.offsetHeight / 2 + "px";
}

function removeAllChild(element){

    for (let child of element.children){
        element.removeChild(child);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Stopwatch</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/main.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 70%;">
            <button align="center" id="button"></button>
        <div>

        <script>
            var button = document.getElementById("button");
            createTriangle(button);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Eu revisei o código diversas vezes e tenho certeza que de não falta ponto e vírgula ou parênteses em qualquer lugar do código. Então o que pode estar gerando este erro 
 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O `for..of` não é suportado pelo IE, me refiro a isto:

```
for (let child of element.children){
```

O `let` é suportado parcialmente pelo IE11, ajuste para:

```
for (var i = element.children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    element.removeChild(element.children[i]);
}
```

O loop tem que ser de trás para frente pois cada vez que um elemento é removido o index é "reajustado"

Aproveite e isole o que é operação matematica do que é "concatenação" isolando com `(...)`

```
triangle.style.left = (element.offsetWidth / 2 - triangle.offsetWidth / 2) + "px";
triangle.style.top = (element.offsetHeight / 2 - triangle.offsetHeight / 2) + "px";
```

É bom tomar cuidado com operações matematicas também e isolar, porque assim você não irá se atrapalhar com os operadores que tem "prioridade"

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação e pela dica!